# Web Scraping - Understat top players data

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I have been trying to scrape data from Understat website (https://understat.com/league/EPL), while I could easily scrape the data for top players, I could not do the same for top teams data. Please help me with this. Here's my code.

````
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

scrape_url="https://understat.com/league/EPL/2020"
page_connect = urlopen(scrape_url)

page_html=BeautifulSoup(page_connect, 'html.parser')
page_html.findAll(name="script")

json_raw_string= page_html.findAll(name="script")[1].string
json_raw_string

start_ind = json_raw_string.index("\\")
stop_ind = json_raw_string.index("')")

data = json_raw_string[start_ind:stop_ind]
data = data.encode("utf8").decode("unicode_escape")
json.loads(data)

df = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(data))
df.head()```
````

Comment: What information do you want to get? The last table with players?

Comment: No, the table above it. The table of teams in order of ranking.

Comment: json_raw_string= page_html.findAll(name="script")[3].string   (choose index 3)

Comment: I tried that, it gives a different table altogether with just one row of Aston Villa.

Comment: interesting but weird too

Answer (score 1):

The data is in index 2, but you need to compute the final table. For example:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

scrape_url = "https://understat.com/league/EPL/2020"
page_connect = urlopen(scrape_url)

page_html = BeautifulSoup(page_connect, "html.parser")
page_html.findAll(name="script")

json_raw_string = page_html.findAll(name="script")[2].string

start_ind = json_raw_string.index("\\")
stop_ind = json_raw_string.index("')")

data = json_raw_string[start_ind:stop_ind]
data = data.encode("utf8").decode("unicode_escape")

data = json.loads(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data.values())
df = df.explode("history")
h = df.pop("history")
df = pd.concat([df.reset_index(drop=True), pd.DataFrame(h.tolist())], axis=1)

# for example print xG column:
print(df.groupby("title")["xG"].sum().sort_values(ascending=False))
```

Prints `xG` column sorted descending:

```
title
Manchester City            77.715218
Liverpool                  72.207518
Chelsea                    68.655594
Manchester United          63.172237
West Ham                   60.338271
Leeds                      59.258638
Leicester                  58.800116
Aston Villa                56.715489
Tottenham                  56.676279
Brighton                   53.819028
Arsenal                    52.247381
Everton                    49.237118
Southampton                45.284568
Newcastle United           43.959188
Fulham                     41.055309
Wolverhampton Wanderers    38.619038
Burnley                    38.127929
Crystal Palace             35.286608
West Bromwich Albion       34.971290
Sheffield United           33.159177
Name: xG, dtype: float64
```